# How to append URL queryParams programmatically in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, router

I want to append the URL queryParams in the browser URL dynamically.
I have a dynamic menu where I can't add any params or function there, just I want global function it will observe the navigation change & it should append the query params in the browser URL.

This is not working.
**RouterResolver before activate the URL I need to add some queryParam in the URL**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, NavigationEnd, NavigationStart, Resolve, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouteingQueryParamsResolver implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {
    constructor(private qp: ShareDataService, private router: Router) {

    }
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {

        const qp = { ...this.qp.getQuery(), ...route.queryParams };
        let urlQuery = '';
        for (var key in qp) {
            if (urlQuery != '') {
                urlQuery += '&';
            }
            urlQuery += key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(qp[key]);
        }
        
        route.queryParams = {urlQuery};
    }
}
```

**Shared funtions to append the queryParams**

```
  @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ShareDataService {
        constructor(private router: Router) {
    
        }
        private content = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
        setQuery(v) {
            this.content.next(v);
        }
    
        getQuery(): Observable<any> {
            return this.content.value;
        }
    
        passQuery(qp: {}) {
            this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
                if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                    this.setQuery(qp);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: it depends on your need, but i want to know something first: do you want to execute a redirection after adding the queryParam to your route or stay in the same pages ?

Comment: Yes after adding queryParams redirection needs happened